# why github doesn't show my updated changes in my repositories?

Tags: github

I am a new learner of github. I create a file in my repositories. Then I realize some missing words. So I change, but github doesn't show the changes when I click " Your site is published at [https://myname.github.io/"](https://myname.github.io/%22) in settings.

Comment: So your problem is nothing changes in your site or nothing changes in your code in repository?

Comment: nothing changes in my site, though I can see the changes in my code  in repository

Comment: now it shows up. weird.

Comment: The pages has to be deployed, this is done asynchronously after you've pushed changes to the branch the pages are based on. About how much time did it take for the pages to become updated?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Github also has a deployment page: `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/deployments`.
Replace `<user>/<repo>` with your GitHub user account name and user GitHub pages repository, in your case `<user>/<user>.github.io`:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<user>.github.io/deployments
```

It will list the deployments occurrence.
Since there is a delay between each deployments, that would explain why you did not see immediately any changes.

Comment: So you mean after this replacement, then users can see immediate changes?

Comment: @Mariana The URL I mention is to allow you to check when the changes are effective. Once published, users will see those changes.